# Find last 4 years

Tags: php, for-loop

How to get an `for loop`to show the last 4 years?

When I use `for($z = date("Y"); $z <= date("Y") + 3; $z++)` I am getting: 2020 & 2021 & 2022 & 2023.

But I need (in this order) 2020 & 2019 & 2018 & 2017.
I have tried `for($z = date("Y"); $z <= date("Y") - 3; $z-1)` but that gives no result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with the last code, but use `$z--` instead of `$z-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping forward, but you need to loop backwards. So,

```
for($z = date("Y"); $z <= date("Y") + 3; $z++)
```

Should be,

```
for($z = date("Y"); $z >= date("Y") - 3; $z--)
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/WC4MQ

You can also use a [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function to get a range of year values.

```
<?php

$current_year = date("Y");

print_r(range($current_year,$current_year-3));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/VTKoH